# How to add keyboard shortcut to launch terminal program?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to add a keyboard shortcut to launch a program I typically open from the terminal. The terminal command I setup for it is `julia` (which points to the relevant binary in my `PATH`).

So I added a keyboard shortcut under Settings (I am in Ubuntu 18.04)

[image]

[image]

but it doesn't do anything. I think maybe the issue is I have to tell it somehow that this is a terminal program?

Comment: you need to provide the full path to the executable.

Comment: @digiwizkid I tried `/usr/bin/julia`, but it also doesn't work. Note that I have a `julia` binary under `/usr/bin/`, which is on my PATH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use: `bash -c "gnome-terminal -x application"` to open a terminal, note that it exits once the application opened stops running.

`bash -c "gnome-terminal -x julia"`

Comment: This works for me but also, if you want to run a program without a terminal popping up use (for example):              ' bash -c "firefox" '          in the settings menu/keyboard shortcuts

Comment: This also works if you just want to launch the terminal on its own `bash -c "gnome-terminal"` (I'd replaced the default "Terminal" program with Alacritty, but still wanted to be able to launch the Gnome terminal too). Just having a custom shortcut with `bash` wasn't enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a .desktop file with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=/path/to/icon/icon.png
Exec=julia
Name=julia
```

Put this file into `~/.local/share/applications` and make it executable by `chmod +x` . Then you should be able to add a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: Have to argue that even though this is a good solution I prefer over keyboard shortcuts, it's also a correct answer to another question.

Comment: @Smurfz87 I will agree that as it is written here, it is not a complete solution to the question. i just have to find out where the desktop file has to be put, so that OP can add a keyboard shortcut to it. Any ideas on that?

Comment: `~/.local/share/applications` ?

Comment: @Smurfz Thank you! I ll  adjust my answer.

Comment: Hi.. I would like to know what will be the keyboard shortcut command to enter in this case? `~/.local/share/applications/julia.desktop` ??

Comment: @PRATAP I do not have gnome installed at the moment, but it might be that you have to enter `gtk-launch julia` or `gtk-launch ~/.local/share/applications/julia.desktop`